# How to export RDBMS Data to Flat File as PDF in Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

hi I'm doing a project in that I need small application i.e I want export the data from a table of my database to flat file generally this flat file in Oracle Data integrator in the form of (.txt) but I want it as a PDF if you have any solution please provide me or any link regarding this please share here

Answer (score 0):

Is is not possible out-of-the-box and I've never read anything related to that.

I would recommend using Oracle BI Publisher instead, which is a tool designed for that.